# Get function type from scala console

Tags: scala

Starting to learn Scala, and I would like to quickly see the method signature in console. 
For example, in Haskell I'd do:

```
Prelude> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This clearly shows the signature of a map function, that is it takes:

1. Function that takes *a* and returns *b*
2. A list of *a*

and returns

1. A list of *b*

which leads to conclusion that 
map function transforms a list of *a* into a list of *b* by applying the function to each element of the list.

Is there a way to obtain the method type in a similar fashion in Scala?

UPDATE:

Trying the answer by Federico Dal Maso, and getting this

```
scala> :type Array.fill
<console>:8: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method fill in object Array of type [T](n1: Int, n2: Int, n3: Int, n4: Int, n5: Int)(elem: => T)(implicit evidence$13: scala.reflect.ClassManifest[T])Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[T]]]]]
and  method fill in object Array of type [T](n1: Int, n2: Int, n3: Int, n4: Int)(elem: => T)(implicit evidence$12: scala.reflect.ClassManifest[T])Array[Array[Array[Array[T]]]]
match expected type ?
       Array.fill
```

Evidently the fill method is overloaded, and :type can't decide which overload to display. So is there a way to display the types of all method overloads?

Comment: You asked about function types. `Array.fill` is not a function, it is a method. Functions cannot be overloaded in Scala, only methods can. So, the problem simply doesn't manifest itself within the scope of your question.

Comment: Yes, I used the terms 'function' and 'method' interchangeably here, which is incorrect, obviously, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 4):

```
scala> :type <expr>
```

display the type of an expression without evaluating it

Answer (score 2):

Scalas REPL can only show types of valid expressions, it is not as powerful as ghci here. Instead you can use [scalex.org](http://scalex.org/) (Scalas Hoogle equivalent). Type in `array fill` and receive:

```
Array fill[T]: (n: Int)(elem: ⇒ T)(implicit arg0: ClassManifest[T]): Array[T]
```

Answer (score 0):

`:type <expr>`

works but if the `expr` is a method then you need to add an underscore to treat it as a partially applied function.

```
scala> def x(op: Int => Double): List[Double] = ???
x: (op: Int => Double)List[Double]

scala> :type x
<console>:15: error: missing arguments for method x;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       x
       ^

scala> :type x _
(Int => Double) => List[Double]
```